# Listing out names of Python dictionary instances

Tags: python, json

I collected public course data from Udemy and put it all in a json file. Each course has an identifier number under which all the data is stored. I can perfectly list out any details I want, except for these identifier numbers.

How can I list out these numbers themselves? Thanks.

```
{
    "153318":
    {
        "lectures data": "31 lectures, 5 hours video",
        "instructor work": "Academy Of Technical Courses, Grow Your Skills Today",
        "title": "Oracle Applications R12 Order Management and Pricing",
        "promotional price": "$19",
        "price": "$20",
        "link": "https://www.udemy.com/oracle-applications-r12-order-management-and-pricing/",
        "instructor": "Parallel Branch Inc"
    },
    "616990":
    {
        "lectures data": "24 lectures, 1.5 hours video",
        "instructor work": "Learning Sans Location",
        "title": "Cloud Computing Development Essentials",
        "promotional price": "$19",
        "price": "$20",
        "link": "https://www.udemy.com/cloud-computing-development-essentials/",
        "instructor": "Destin Learning"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Python code? The way to do this depends on what you've done so far.

Comment: `dict.keys()` should list all keys

Answer (score 3):

You want the `keys` of that dictionnary.

```
import json
with open('course.json') as json_file:
    course=json.load(json_file)

print course.keys()
```

giving : 
`[u'616990', u'153318']`

Answer (score 0):

Parse the json into a python dict, then loop over the keys

```
parsed = json.loads(input)

for key in parsed.keys():
    print(key)
```

Comment: That's it! I didn't add .keys(). Thanks.